# Possibility of a multilanguage 'source' name with Twincat Eventlogger

Tags: plc, twincat

Roald has written an excellent guide for the Twincat Eventlogger.

https://roald87.github.io/twincat/2020/11/03/twincat-eventlogger-plc-part.html
https://roald87.github.io/twincat/2021/01/20/twincat-eventlogger-hmi-part.html

For us this is exactly what we want, there is however 1 thing I haven't figured out. How to get the sourcename of the alarm in multiple languages in the HMI. `params::sourceName` gives the path in the software (example: `MAIN.fbConveyor1.Cylinder1`) This path can be customized when initializing the alarm (as Roald has shown). This doesn't work in my case, since I would like to define a generic alarm (example: "Cilinder not retracted within maximum time") that is instantiated multiple times.

I was thinking of using the source as a way to show the operator where the alarm occurs. We use this way (path) already for saving machine settings among other things. The machines we build are installed all over the world, so multilanguage is a must.

Beckhoff does support multilanguage alarm names (when defined), but the source is not defined, but dynamically generated.

Anyone have an idea how this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then being able to parameterize the event text with information of the source of the problem should help you out.

If you define the event text as `Cylinder {0} has not retracted in time.` then you can add the arguments of that text during runtime.

```
IF bRaiseAlarm THEN
    bRaiseAlarm := FALSE;
    fbAlarm.ipArguments.Clear().AddString('Alice');
    fbAlarm.Raise(0);
END_IF
```

However, since this also stated in the articles you mentioned, I am unsure if this would solve your problem.

'Alice' in this example, can be hard to localize. The following options come to my mind.

1. The string can be based on an ENUM. Enums can have textlist support, so if you add your translations there, that should allow multilingual output. However... this does require a lot of setup, placing translations inside your code, and making sure the PLC application is aware of the language that the parameter should use.
2. Use tags to mark the source device, as tags can be language invariant. It is not the most user-friendly method, but it could work for you. It would become something like: "Cylinder 'AA.1123' did not retract in time.". 'AA.1123' as a tag would have to be stored inside your PLC code as a string. You will have to trust that your operator can relate the tag back to the actual source.

Hopefully, this helped, or else please help me understand the problem better.

Comment: Thanks for both of the options. I can't really think of another way to solve it. Essentially I want to show the operator 'Conveyor 1 - cylinder 1' has not retracted in time. If the same function block for cylinder is used somewhere else it could be 'Conveyor 2 - pusher left' has not retracted in time (for example).

Comment: The ENUM / texlist way might not work if we have multiple clients, each with a different language. The code will throw the alarm, and put the parameter in there in a specific language. 

I guess the tag way is the easiest solution, this might however be difficult to implement in our machine...

Comment: Ok cool. I was also not a fan of the ENUM method. You can always request the tag as an input parameter from the parent FB. But yea.. naming objects like "pusher left" will become difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the option of using an event as a translatable argument. For this you have to create an additional event and use this as an argument.

```
fbArguments.Clear().AddEventReferenceEx(TC_EVENTS.ApplicationEvents.LocalizedArgument);
fbLogger.SendMessageEx(TC_EVENTS.ApplicationEvents.Message, fbSourceInfo, 0, fbArguments);
```

In this case the 'LocalizedArgument' is an additional event and the 'Message' event is using it as argument: Message Arg = {0}.
This is how it is possible to localize 'Alice' from Rudi's example.